# Writing contents of ByteArrayOutputStream to a file using NIO FileChannel

Tags: java, nio, filechannel, bytearrayoutputstream

I have a method that generates a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and I want to put those contents in a file using `FileChannel`. With `FileOutputStream`, I could do this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = MyClass.myMethod(); // get my stream
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("somefile"); // I want to write to "somefile"
out.writeTo(baos); // write
```

How can I do this using `FileChannel`? I know I can convert `baos` to a byte array, then convert that to a `ByteBuffer`, and then I can finally use `FileChannel.write()` to write stuff. But this would mean dumping the contents of the stream into memory and it is fairly large.

Unless I'm mistaken, converting the `ByteArrayOutputStream` into an `InputStream` of some kind, and then using `Channels.newChannel(InputStream in)`, to finally use `FileChannel.transferFrom()` will run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it from the other end: rather than wrapping `ByteArrayOutputStream` into a channel, you could wrap your `FileChannel` into `OutputStream`, and complete the write by calling `out.writeTo`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = MyClass.myMethod1();
FileChannel channel = MyClass.myMethod2();
OutputStream out = Channels.newOutputStream(channel);
out.writeTo(baos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to *not* generate a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. It's poor technique, and doesn't scale. Pass it an `OutputStream`, or `WriteableByteChannel`, and have it write its own output.